# Obtaining payment dates of debit using credit payment dates and aggregates in SQL - slow query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Edit2:** CTE was the reason for the slow query. Problem solved.

**Edit:** Instead of updating, I'm going to create another column of payment date. The following code works perfectly however it is incredibly slow. Is there any other method to do this faster?

```
WITH sum_data AS (SELECT CustomerID
                   , ISSUEDATE
                   , DEBIT
                   , CREDIT
                   , SUM(DEBIT) over(PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                                     ORDER BY ISSUEDATE
                                     ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) SUM_DEBIT
                   , SUM(CREDIT) over(PARTITION BY CustomerID
                                      ORDER BY ISSUEDATE
                                      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) SUM_CREDIT
               FROM Test_Table)
SELECT d.CustomerID
 , d.ISSUEDATE
 , d.DEBIT
 , d.CREDIT
 , (SELECT MIN(ISSUEDATE) 
               FROM sum_data d2
               WHERE d2.SUM_CREDIT >= d.SUM_DEBIT
                 AND d2.CustomerID  = d.CustomerID) PAYMENTDATE
FROM sum_data d
WHERE DEBIT != 0
```

**Pre-Edit:** I have a dataset that shows transaction information for different customers. Credit lines have issue date and payment date the same because they are issued and paid at the same time. However for the debit lines payment date will be when that debit is cleared by the credit. So starting from the bottom, we have 4 debit before a credit is entered. 1398.83 credit clears the amount of 1336.13 debit so I want to update the last row with the payment date of 9/20/2018. 2672 of credit above it covers the second to last row of 1398.83 so that row's payment date should be 9/22/2018. Remaining balance of (1398.83-1336.13) + (2672 - 1398.83) does not cover the remaining debits so we will keep on checking if new credit rows cover the debit amounts and will start clearing debits (as in updating payment date) from the last entry and when the debit is cleared we will update the payment date with the clearing credit row's payment date as in the above examples. This will be done for all different customer IDs (partition by).

```
CustomerID  ISSUEDATE   DEBIT   CREDIT  
M00008      4/2/2019    1345.53 0       
M00008      3/19/2019   0       1336.13 
M00008      3/18/2019   0       1403.4  
M00008      3/4/2019    1406.13 0       
M00008      3/4/2019    1336.13 0       
M00008      2/28/2019   0       1336.13 
M00008      2/21/2019   0       1399.19 
M00008      2/4/2019    1403.4  0       
M00008      2/4/2019    1336.13 0       
M00008      1/28/2019   0       1513    
M00008      1/22/2019   0       1337.94 
M00008      1/4/2019    1398.83 0       
M00008      1/4/2019    1336.13 0       
M00008      12/3/2018   1513.03 0       
M00008      12/3/2018   1336.13 0       
M00008      11/19/2018  0       2958    
M00008      11/19/2018  0       2908.25 
M00008      11/5/2018   1461.56 0       
M00008      11/2/2018   1367.92 0       
M00008      10/20/2018  0       1336.13 
M00008      10/19/2018  0       1398.83 
M00008      10/3/2018   1489.94 0       
M00008      10/2/2018   1541.03 0       
M00008      9/22/2018   0       2672    
M00008      9/20/2018   0       1398.83 
M00008      9/3/2018    1398.83 0       
M00008      9/3/2018    1336.13 0       
M00008      8/3/2018    1398.83 0       
M00008      8/2/2018    1336.13 0
```

Output from query above on this dataset:

```
CustomerID  ISSUEDATE   DEBIT    CREDIT PAYMENTDATE
M00008      2018-08-02  1336.13  0.00   2018-09-20
M00008      2018-08-03  1398.83  0.00   2018-09-22
M00008      2018-09-03  1398.83  0.00   2018-10-19
M00008      2018-09-03  1336.13  0.00   2018-10-20
M00008      2018-10-02  1541.03  0.00   2018-11-19
M00008      2018-10-03  1489.94  0.00   2018-11-19
M00008      2018-11-02  1367.92  0.00   2018-11-19
M00008      2018-11-05  1461.56  0.00   2018-11-19
M00008      2018-12-03  1513.03  0.00   2019-01-22
M00008      2018-12-03  1336.13  0.00   2019-01-28
M00008      2019-01-04  1398.83  0.00   2019-02-21
M00008      2019-01-04  1336.13  0.00   2019-02-21
M00008      2019-02-04  1403.40  0.00   2019-03-18
M00008      2019-02-04  1336.13  0.00   2019-03-18
M00008      2019-03-04  1406.13  0.00   NULL
M00008      2019-03-04  1336.13  0.00   NULL
M00008      2019-04-02  1345.53  0.00   NULL
```

Comment: It is possible, but I think it's the kind of question people get paid $200k+ a year to work on. Do you have some sort of a query you wrote yourself to solve this problem that you need help with? I guess this could take a professional a day to write and make sure it's bullet-proof so it's a bit unreasonable to expect someone to write the entire query for you for +25 in reputation.

Comment: I added the code I used and changed the wording a bit. Instead of updating I created another column called Payment date and the code I added above works perfectly. However it takes a long time. I was wondering if there is another method to do this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using select within select statement will always have effect on performance. For your query, using CROSS APPLY should yield the results faster.

```
WITH sum_data AS (SELECT CustomerID
               , ISSUEDATE
               , DEBIT
               , CREDIT
               , SUM(DEBIT) over(PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                                 ORDER BY ISSUEDATE
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) SUM_DEBIT
               , SUM(CREDIT) over(PARTITION BY CustomerID
                                  ORDER BY ISSUEDATE
                                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) SUM_CREDIT
           FROM Test_Table)
 SELECT d.CustomerID
      , d.ISSUEDATE
      , d.DEBIT
      , d.CREDIT
      , PaymentDate
   FROM sum_data d
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(ISSUEDATE) AS PaymentDate
           FROM sum_data d2
           WHERE d2.SUM_CREDIT >= d.SUM_DEBIT
             AND d2.CustomerID  = d.CustomerID) t
   WHERE DEBIT != 0
```

Comment: Note that a `cross apply` works in a similar fashion to an `inner join` in that where there is no matching record in the `apply` nothing will be returned.  If you require `left join` type behaviourn you can use an `outer apply`.